# NS forwarding for CMS future thinking

Tags: dns, forwarding, cname, a-records

I'm designing a CMS,
my users want to attach theyr domain to the websites they build,
i can give them the NS of my storage company, but my fears are if i change storage company,
than im changing NSs too and thats not possible.

is there a way to do ns forwarding or a paid ns service that forwards to a desired ns so i can tell my users to forward theyr NS to my NS service and mine will transfer the connection to the current NS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answare i solved this by setting up my own dns server called "BIND" in linux, still configuring it but it seems to solve the problem with forwarding all the traffic from ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com to the same ip (current hosting) and if i change storage company i set everything up and just change the ip to forward to.